# How to block NIR (850 nm) by dry fog or film?

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation

I have several sectors in the large open space which have NIR 850 nm emitters and I should isolate them from each other. There is no way to create doors or walls. Ideally, radiation should be absorbed rather than reflected. So is it possible to use dry fog or film like this one https://www.weetect.com/tint-film/ir-blocking-film/?

Comment: As it says "heat resistant film", this is probably meant to block thermal IR, wavelengths around 10 micrometers.

Comment: @Pieter Got it, thanks! But is there a film which blocks at least 850 nm?

Comment: I do not know. Are these diodes emitting signals? It may be easier and more reliable to make the signals distinguishable.

Comment: @Pieter it's possible but will require much of effort. I am currently trying to find the way how to isolate emitters rather than hack them.

Comment: @PavelNuzhdin do you really need to "isolate (the emitters) from *each other*" or just keep some receiver from seeing more than one emitter a time.  Pieter's comment might be executed by using different frequencies of pulsed/modulated emitters, or slightly different wavelengths and really good filters.